# In R: Build a logistic regression model to predict the probability

Tags: r, logistic-regression

Build a logistic regression model to predict the probability that a student will be in the honors class, based on information we know about the student: Male , read = 50, math = 60. What is the probability?

For building the model, the only variables are female ( have to seperate gender from code) , Honors, read, and math

Model I want to show is :

```
m5 <- glm(hon ~ female + math + read + female * math * read, data = honor, family = binomial)
summary(m5)
```

[summary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22W0y.png)

Male is 0 Female is 1 as levels when I go deeper as a Binary predictor for model. How can I add this on the model?

Is this correct model to build to extract logit values to make a probability?

Comment: Sorry, how will you predict Male without Male? Why is it necessary to separate gender from the model? I honestly don't get why it would make sense to include only female, then maybe drop gender altogether?

Comment: Only data given is female, as in it has to be a binary variable automatic. The questiontion asks itself to predict if male , read is 50 and math is 60 .

Comment: I understand the math and read, its just tying the gender in the problem to make it work. I may be over complicating it.

Comment: But you already have gender "tied into" the model! The coefficient for `female` shows the difference in association with the outcome between being female vs. being male.

Comment: I understand that you guys are right. One question ,  Would having female*male*read in my model  be the right approach??

Answer (score 0):

```
predict(m5, newdata = data.frame(female = 0, read = 50, math = 60))
```

Comment: Well you could make it more compact: `m5 <- glm(hon ~  female * math * read, data = honor, family = binomial)`. The `*` operator expands into the main effects, the two-way interactions, and the three-way interaction. If you want to simplify the model I would look at the analysis of deviance table and the chi-squared statistics, e.g. `anova(m5, test = "Chisq")`